# Why do I have overlapping toolbars on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome, taskbar

Since I've upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10, I've had one toolbar hovering over the other toolbar.  The hidden toolbar was installed when I installed the Gnome app.  Why won't this second toolbar go away?